# Can someone explain the "Block" concept in Piranha.vNext CMS?

Tags: piranha-cms

I was playing around with the new Piranha.vNext cms here - https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha.vNext.

There is no documentation on "Blocks". But it looks like a replacement or complimentary to the "Pages". Can someone please shed more light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Blocks is to be able to easily add global chunks of HTML that can be used anywhere in the site. The content of pages or posts are always related to that entity, but Blocks have no relation and can be used in any way you see fit!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thank you! PageMgr items are missing in the latest source code. Hence the doubt that "Block" might be replacing "Page" eventually.

Comment: That's just because it's not finished yet :) And the whole content model is under revision so there's chance that it will change a bit anyway. Right now it looks more likely that we'll be moving away from Pages & Posts to a more general Content model that will handle both in order to keep both the codebase and projects leaner!

Comment: Looking forward to the new design :). But for now, I added the Page model items and feel comfortable with it's usage. I like the idea of reusable Blocks as well.